# Wasserstein-like measure for disconnected spaces

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces, information-theory, information-geometry

Does there exist a Wasserstein-like measure for difference between probability distributions, where the space on which the probabilities are defined is not connected?

E.g. a distribution over six states; three of these have defined distances with respect to one another (such as [0 1 2;1 0 1;2 1 0]); and the other three as well; but the two sets of three do not have distances defined with respect to one another.

Is there some Wasserstein-something-else hybrid that has been explored (or something else) that addresses this situation?

thank you!

Comment: The obvious approach is to set the distance between two disconnected states to infinity...

Comment: But then it's still essentially a Wasserstein metric, right? And then you get infinite difference between distributions on disconnected spaces; but if you used e.g. KLD to compare them, you would not get an infinite distance. So I am wondering about something like a KLD-Wasserstein hybrid, where any distribution can be analyzed, but if any part of it is over a space that information is taken into account. Maybe it doesn't make any sense?

Comment: Well, suppose you have two probability distributions $p_1$ and $p_2$ on a space with two connected components say $A$ and $B$. As long as both distributions assign the same probability mass to $A$, i.e. $p_1(A) = p_2(A)$, and similarly $p_1(B)=p_2(B)$, then you still have a finite Wasserstein distance between the two distributions. If not, then you have to explain how one can transport probability mass between $A$ and $B$, which a priori is impossible given your statement that the two components are disconnected.

Comment: I suppose you could consider two modified distributions $p_1'$ and $p_2'$ such that $p_1'(A)=p_2'(A)$ and $p_1'(B)=p_2'(B)$, and then compute a cost of the form $D_{KL}(p_1'|p_1) + W(p_1',p_2') + D_{KL}(p_2'|p_1)$, but since the KL divergence has units of entropy and the Wasserstein metric has units of distance, it's not clear what the right scaling between the terms should be.

Answer (score 2):

I think the generalization you're probably looking for is the more general transportation cost/distance, of which the Wasserstein distance is just a special case.

Take *any* 2 probability spaces $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\nu)$.  Define a *transportation cost*

$$
c(x,y):X\times Y\rightarrow [0,\infty]
$$ This represents the cost of transporting 1 "unit" of mass from $X$ to $Y$.  Then, you can immediately write down the generalized transportation distance

$$
T_c(\mu,\nu) = \inf_{\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)}\int c(x,y)d\pi
$$ where $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the set of joint probability measures on $X\times Y$ such that the marginals are $\mu$ and $\nu$ i.e. $\int_X d\pi = d\nu$, $\int_Y d\pi = d\mu$.  This is the generalization of the Wasserstein distance.

The definition of the cost function is entirely up to you (though some will be easier to work with than others!)  The Wasserstein distance chooses $c(x,y) = d(x,y)^p$ in the case when both probability measures on defined on a *common* metric space, because this is convenient and allows us to prove more theorems.  You can prove pretty general things without this assumption, though - see the two books by Villani and another two by Rachev + Ruschendorf, or maybe *User's guide to optimal transport*, a set of notes on Arxiv by Ambrosio.   For instance, as soon as $X$ and $Y$ are *individually* complete separable metric spaces and the cost is lower semicontinuous, you can define the transportation distance and it has nice(ish) properties.  See chapter 4 in Villani's *Optimal Transport, Old and New* (available on his website, I believe).

From a more philosophical point of view, you might ask yourself the following question: if the two spaces "aren't connected", how are you going to measure the cost of transporting material from one to the other?  You really need a "path" to get from one to the other in order to transport mass.  Otherwise the transportation cost should always be infinite (intuitively).  If you can answer "why" the two sets are disconnected, this might help you define a logical cost function.  Otherwise I don't see how a transportation distance even makes sense.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reading suggestions, and useful comments. I'll see what I can find with some more serious reading. I see the problem with using a transport metric on a disconnected space.. I guess really I am wondering if it's possible to do some sort of information measure where a transportation measure contributes where possible, but otherwise something like a KLD takes over. Thanks!